# Monte Carlo Results in OpenOffice Calc

Tags: simulation

I have a simulation set up in OpenOffice.  I want to display the results of the simulation, for say 100 replications, but I can't seem to work out how to do it.  Obviously if you just copy the result to a cell and drag it down 100 rows, they all show the same figure.

Either a macro is necessary or there is a built in way.  Neither of which I know.

Basically, the equivalent to http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tpIhQuxQeNs

Comment: In case anyone is wondering.  I managed to write a macro for this:

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I created a macro as so:

```
Sub PasteSpecialNoFormula 
dim args3(0) as new com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue
args3(0).Name = "SelectedFormat"
args3(0).Value = 1
Dim document As Object
document   = ThisComponent.CurrentController.Frame
dispatcher = createUnoService("com.sun.star.frame.DispatchHelper")

oDesktop = createUnoService("com.sun.star.frame.Desktop") 
oDocument = ThisComponent 
oSheet1 = oDocument.Sheets.getByIndex(0) 
oSheet2 = oDocument.Sheets.getByIndex(0) 

Dim i As Long, n As Long
n = 1000
for i = 1 to n

oFromRange = oSheet1.getCellRangeByName("B464:C464") 
oToCell = oSheet2.getCellByPosition(1,466+i) 

oDocument.CurrentController.Select(oFromRange) 
dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:Copy", "", 0, Array()) 

oDocument.CurrentController.Select(oToCell) 

dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:ClipboardFormatItems", "", 0, args3())

 next i
 End Sub
```